# Why do both sine and cosine exist?

Tags: trigonometry, math-history

Cosine is just a change in the argument of sine, and vice versa.

$$\sin(x+\pi/2)=\cos(x)$$
$$\cos(x-\pi/2)=\sin(x)$$

So why do we have both of them? Do they both exist simply for convenience in defining the other trig functions?

Comment: If you look at the $\cos$ and $\sin$ from a geometric point of view, it's quite clear why it's useful to have both of them.

Comment: You really mean, "why do we name them both?" Because it is quite clear from your equation why one exists if the other does.

Comment: There are things like the versine which are not used any more - it's just a balance between reducing the number of functions to remember, and increasing the number of ways we can simplify expressions.

Comment: For example, the points on the circle of radius $r$ centered on the origin are compactly parameterized by $(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$.  In many cases it is convenient to deal with separate functions (one even, one odd) rather than hammering the round peg into the square hole each time.

Comment: Early tables had the equivalent of sine only, for the reasons you describe. Later tables also sometimes had tan, since division was a nuisance.  I do not recall any cosine tables.

Comment: Why do we have either $\sin$ or $\cos$, when we have the more fundamental $e^x$?
$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\qquad\qquad \cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Comment: Many definition in mathematics comes with pairs

Comment: …and once you get to studying Fourier series, having a function that is even and a function that is odd proves convenient.

Comment: @ZevChonoles.would you be able easily to solve trig problems imvolving triangles etc using the exponential forms?

Comment: @Zev: Why do we have $e^x$ when we have the more fundamental $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^x$? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: is that the make me one with everything function? :-)

Comment: [They actually don't exist](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/real.pdf)

Comment: People started using the sIne and the compliment's-sine (aka cosine) shortly after realizing that trigonometry had more uses other than the production of star maps.

Comment: Historically, trig came first. That's why they are both named. Wikipedia traces it back to ancient times. Different language but still one referencing the other.

Comment: 1 + 1 = 2
Why do we have both of them? 2s are just 1s added up.

Comment: They exists just for convenience

Comment: Why we have substraction when it is just summation with different sign. Why we have division when it is just multiplication by inverse and so on. It is just simplification of notation.

Comment: sine exists and cosine co-exists!

Comment: @Plutor: [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) allows us to get rid of numbers altogether!

Comment: Why do we have words for both "good" and "bad"? Couldn't we just say "good" and "ungood"? Hey, I'm thinking of inventing a New way of Speaking based on this principle.

Comment: For those who doesn't understand @Jay joke https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak

Comment: @user170039: Because it made a nice joke?

Comment: I remember someone arguing against redundant operators in a programming language until it was pointed out that you didn't need "+", because users could always write "--".

Comment: @Jay , "ungood" is not a legal replacement for "bad". Bad is a noun, ungood is a verb. :))

Comment: math is always simplest.:-)

Comment: Some of the answerers here seem to lack understanding or memory of how most students stub their toe on this question. It comes from spending an evening in one of the many facets of sine (usually thinking about sine *waves*) and forgetting the geometric side.

Answer (score 159):

You seem to be asking why we name them both, rather than why they exist, since the very relationships you've written shows that if one exists, the other does, too.

Essentially, *all* mathematical notation and names, except for a very small subset, are for convenience/clarity/human communication. Math does not require that we name any function consistently across separate proofs, but it becomes much easier to communicate and think about things when we do.

I prefer the relationship:

$$\sin(x)=\cos(\pi/2-x)\\\cos(x)=\sin(\pi/2-x)$$ since this is symmetric and obviously geometric when $0\leq x\leq \pi/2$, and because this is also the relationship between "tangent" and "cotangent" and "secant" and "cosecant." It indicates a duality in these functions.

It is certainly something of a paradox that adding more names often simplifies our understanding. In particular, if you defined only one, it would give you a sense that one of these functions was "primary." There is a hint of that error even in the names "sine" and "cosine," which vaguely implies that "sine" is primary, but it would be particularly strong if we only defined "sine" and never defined "cosine." We would have a harder time grasping the duality that happens in trig functions.

---

If you actually must start with one function, most mathematicians wouldn't start with $\cos x$ or $\sin x,$ they'd start with the complex-valued function: $\operatorname{cis}(x)=\cos(x)+i\sin(x).$ This has the property $\operatorname{cis}(x)\operatorname{cis}(y)=\operatorname{cis}(x+y),$ and can also be written as $e^{ix}.$ You can define $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ in terms of $\operatorname{cis} x:$

$$\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\operatorname{cis}(x)+\operatorname{cis}(-x)\right)\\
\sin x=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\operatorname{cis}(x)-\operatorname{cis}(-x)\right)$$

---

Addition: I recently heard, in a lecture that covered some of the accomplishments of the early Muslim world, that they acquired knowledge of the sine function from India, and developed the other trigonometric functions. So if you want someone to blame, we can blame them.

Comment: In my opinion, cosine seems primary. Also, _why didn't people define $\sec:=\frac1\sin$?_ I have this extra "co" to deal with whenever I invert the value and it's so annoying…

Comment: It does bug me that $\sec$ is related to $\cos$ and $\csc$ is related to $\sin$, because the "co" switches places. However, geometrically it makes sense: things without "co" (sine, tangent and secant) are to do with the [sine length](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Unitcircledefs.svg/640px-Unitcircledefs.svg.png?1441048166953) in the unit circle, which is vertical; meanwhile things with the "co" are to do with the [cosine length](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Unitcirclecodefs.svg/640px-Unitcirclecodefs.svg.png), which is horizontal.

Comment: @columbus8myhw if on the unit circle, you draw the vertical line tangent to it at $(1,0)$, then take its intersection with angle ray (the other along the positive $x$-axis) then... (1) the height above the x-axis is the *tangent* of the angle, while (2) the length segment that *cuts across* the circle along the ray to the vertical line is the *secant* of the angle. Well, it might not satisfy you as an optimal naming convention, but that's why it was defined that way.

Comment: Alternatively, $\sin,\sec,\tan$ are all increasing on $(0,\pi/2)$. But yeah, it bugged me when I took trig way back when.

Comment: secant function is useful when you're creating navigation tables.  For example, see this  https://books.google.com/books?id=wpxDAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA287&lpg=PA287&dq=secant+navigation+table&source=bl&ots=vq5ZhcLcvo&sig=U28WLGLqX-UfGTlFZ62pac1H0i8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMIoYfz24zUxwIVg20-Ch0eSgCw#v=onepage&q=secant%20navigation%20table&f=false

Comment: There's certainly a lot of reason that in older times, you'd have different lookup tables for the different functions, because a lot of navigation used trig (and logarithms, and other things,) and ship navigators in the past were not always the best-educated. I've been reading about Nathaniel Bowditch, and he trained a lot of uneducated men to navigate, based on lookup tables and addition only, so the possibilities of error were less. @Chan-HoSuh

Comment: On the issue of sec versus cosec and their relationships to sin and cos, see [Is there a relationship between trigonometric functions and their “co” functions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1227697/72968)

Comment: What I take away from this is that wherever there is a $\sin$ or a $\cos$, the other is often not far behind, as with two sides of a coin, and that what trig functions one uses to write something is an arbitrary decision (this non-uniqueness being the source of many textbook exercises of the form 'prove this identity between these apparently different formulae'), so there is little point in privileging only some with names.  By the way, love your 'history' of how the three functions to get the co- prefix and the three not to were chosen, even if the explanation is likely a fictitious one.

Comment: "Essentially, all mathematical notation and names, except for a very small subset, are for convenience/clarity/human communication. ": could you say more about that last part? Which aren't? (I think it would help to understand what you mean)

Comment: There isn't a specific set of symbols or concepts that *necessarily* need to be defined, but mathematics requires enough expressiveness to at least state enough things. so, for example, of propositional calculus, we can get away with one symbol if we want, rather than the usual three "and, or, not." What concepts we start from is somewhat flexible, but often trying to come up with minimal sets of such definitions and/or axioms is just a parlor game. That said, there is a topic called, "reverse mathematics," which asks what axioms are necessary for various theorems, for example. @NajibIdrissi

Comment: Why did I read this answer in Morgan Freeman's voice?

Comment: Because I'm an old old man. Okay, not Morgan Freeman old, but I did just have a big birthday. @MonK

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I'm curious, what makes cosine seem more primary to you? To me, the prefix co- usually refers to something secondary, such as co-conspirator, etc.

Comment: @Ovi Trying to remember what I was thinking two years ago: When you write them out in term of Euler's formula, cosine is $\dfrac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}2$ and sine is $\dfrac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$; doesn't the former look a lot more primary and clean? In addition, $\cos(n\theta)$ can be written as a polynomial in terms of $\cos(\theta)$, while $\sin(n\theta)$ cannot be written as a polynomial of $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Ah okay thanks.

Comment: The standard parametric equation for a circle, $(\cos t,\sin t)$, puts cosine first. The [product-to-sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) also make cosine look more primary, arguably. @Ovi

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Good points, much deeper than my own reason haha

Comment: @Ovi IMO cosine is more primary because it is the real component of $e^{iθ}$ whereas sine is the imaginary component. Also, cosine's Taylor series expansion uses even monomials whereas sine uses odd monomials.

Answer (score 113):

$$
\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha =1,
$$
$$
\sin^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \left( \alpha + \frac{\pi}{2} \right) =1.
$$
Which one do you prefer?

*Post scriptum*: of course this is not a deep answer, but I think that sometimes mathematicians prefer elegance to logical "economy".

Comment: You should make a "PS" to explain what the "post scriptum" means

Answer (score 34):

The question is ridiculous. (I'm afraid to say.)

It's equivalent to asking **"Why are there words for both North and South?"**

(Of course you could just use "negative North" at all times, if desired.)

In my opinion, one would only ask the question at hand, if, one has rather naively "just noticed" - let's put it that way - that sine and cosine are complementary.

Note too that, indeed, in English **co**-sine is simply "sine" ... with the appropriate prefix!! Just as you'd expect.

Again to make analogy, one could ask questions such as "why do we label both matter and antimatter!" or "Why label both up and down?"

It's clear, traditional, and expected in languages that there are matching terms for complementary qualities {rather than, let us say "minimalistically," using only the one and then the negative of it} ...

heaven and hell, paradis et enfer.

Comment: Very nice logic..!! I like it..

Comment: Great answer. I'll just point out the spelling of 'compl**e**mentary' http://www.mathopenref.com/complement.html

Comment: A double plus good answer if ever there was one.

Comment: If anything, I think it's more like asking "Why are there words for both North and East" - almost exactly so.

Comment: I had exactly the same thought--this is like asking why we have words for "up" and "down" when you could just use one word all the time. (I'm going not down this mountain right now!) Sine is opposite over hypotenuse, and cosine is adjacent over hypotenuse. May as well ask why a triangle has three sides!

Comment: Coming back to this answer 5 years later, and I still don't like it.

Comment: This has a lot of upvotes for an answerless rant about the question.

Answer (score 20):

I think it's conceptually cleaner to have both $\cos$ and $\sin$ as distinct notations, for the following reason: in my opinion, it's a bit of a "coincidence" that each of the functions $\{\cos,\sin\}$ can be described as translations of the other.

My preferred definition of these two functions is the following: first, position yourself at $(1,0)$ on the unit circle. Then start walking anticlockwise at unit speed. It follows that if the time elapsed is $t$, your $x$-coordinate will be $\cos t$ and your $y$-coordinate will be $\sin t$.

But notice that, in general, this way of producing pairs of functions (namely: positioning yourself on a curve and walking at unit speed, and then projecting onto the $x$ and $y$ coordinate axes) won't usually result in a pair of functions such that each can be defined as a translation of the other. The ability to define $\cos$ and $\sin$ in terms of each other is *specifically* a quirk of circles centered at the origin. In some sense, it's kind of a coincidence.

By the way, this viewpoint explains why $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$; it's because you're walking on the curve defined by $x^2+y^2= 1$. This also explains why $\cos(0) = 1$ and $\sin(0)= 0$; it's because we positioned ourselves at $(1,0)$ to begin with. It also explains why $(\cos' t)^2+(\sin't)^2= 1$; it's because you're walking at unit speed. And finally, this explains why $\sin'(0)>0;$. It's because we chose to start walking anticlockwise. I'm pretty sure these four conditions (listed below for your convenience) completely characterize the ordered pair ($\cos,\sin$) among all ordered pairs of differentiable functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

1. $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$
2. $\cos(0) = 1, \sin(0) = 0$
3. $(\cos't)^2+(\sin't)^2 = 1$
4. $\sin'(0) > 0$

Comment: Those conditions aren't complete.  Be nice and provide a proof with the correct conditions :)  (easy counterexample, stick with cosine but instead of sine use negative sine)

Comment: In some sense, it's a kind of coincidence, but in another sense it isn't; the reason we care at all about parameterizing circles is precisely that they're symmetric, and the ability to express $\sin$ and $\cos$ in terms of each other is a consequence of that symmetry...

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh, thanks for the counterexamples; I've added a fourth condition to eliminate the problem. Honestly, I really have no idea how to prove this. Analysis is a bit of a blind spot for me at the moment. Feel free to edit your own proof into the question. I've community-wikified it.

Comment: @goblin,Of course your conditions work, since they translate (in words) to "$(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ is the arclength parameterization of the unit circle, starting at $(0,1)$ and moving in the positive direction", which is basically the definition of sine and cosine used most commonly in calculus courses.  It is not too hard to show, inductively, that all orders of derivatives at $0$ are what they are supposed to be, by differentiating implicitly.  Try it out! So this definition agrees with the power series definition, at least.

Comment: There are other isometries of the plane that will preserve those conditions (For instance, imagine the unit circle being centered at (1,1)).  You need to rule them out.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh, I'm not following. Note that $\cos^2 t+\sin^2t=1$ forces us to remain on unit circle centered at the origin.

Comment: @goblin yes you're right

Answer (score 12):

Suppose you're walking counterclockwise around the unit circle, starting at the point with coordinates $(1, 0)$. When you've walked a distance of $\theta$, your coordinates are $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.

To me, that's why it's natural to name both cosine and sine: it takes two coordinates to describe a point in the plane, and both of those coordinates deserve names.

Comment: While not as "deep" as the other answers; I think this is the best.  You can take any curve in the plane or on the earth and ask for the coordinates (x,y) and have two functions x(t),y(t) .  If you constrain the curve to be a circle (constant radius) then the coordinates reflect the symmetry of your _chosen_ curve and are thus degenerate in the questioners sense.

Answer (score 11):

Mathematics is about making definitions that are as elegant and nice as possible, and allow your conclusions to easily or straightforwardly follow. In this case, it actually turns out the most elegant function, and the most helpful to understanding, is not cosine or sine. It is
$$
\textbf{cis}(x) = e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x.
$$
Of course, this is a complex-valued function--it takes in a real number $x$ and returns the point on the unit circle at angle $x$. But all of the properties you know about sine and cosine can be derived from this.

But more importantly, we see that $\cos$ and $\sin$ naturally arise *in tandem*, one as the real part and one as the imaginary part of $\text{cis}(x)$. So it makes little sense to define only one of the two without defining both.

Why do we define $\cos$ and $\sin$ at all, if we could just use $\text{cis}$? Because we often work with real numbers, and it is nice to have names for the real number functions arising from the complex exponential so that we don't have to insert imaginary numbers into real-number expressions that eventually cancel out. Also for historical reasons.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest two reasons why we have both sin and cos.

First, *historically*, those who originally developed trigonometry started down the path of defining both functions, and then discovered various relationships between the two functions.  Rather than redefine the work they did, we retain the functions as separate entities.

Second, for *simplicity*.  The equation for a circular arc for example, can be more simply written as $x=\cos(t)$, $y=\sin(t)$, than as $x=\cos(t)$, $y=\cos(t-\pi/2)$.

If we are really trying to economize on functions, we could rewrite the tangent function $\tan(x)=\sin(x)/\cos(x)$ as $\cos(x-\pi/2)/\cos(x)$, but I think it would be more difficult to talk about the function this way, or to describe some of its remarkable properties, such as $\tan'(x)=\sec^2(x)$ or $\tan^2(x)+1=\sec^2(x)$.

From these two identities we can deduce:  $\tan'(x) = \tan^2(x)+1$, which means $\tan(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation: $y' = y^2+ 1$.

I'll leave it to you to rewrite this derivation using $\cos(x)$ only.   :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

- Why do we say up and down instead of just up, since down is just reversed up?
- Why is liquid measured in liters when you could just use cubic decimeters?

Because each unit or word is appropriate to the thing it's measuring.

A triangle has three sides. In a right triangle, each side's length divided by another side's length gives a ratio that reliably relates to one of the (non-right) angles of the triangle. You'll notice that the permutations of 3 items taken 2 at a time is 6, which just happens to be how many basic trigonometric functions there are (not counting their inverses):

```
opposite / hypotenuse : sine        hypotenuse / opposite : cosecant
adjacent / hypotenuse : cosine      hypotenuse / adjacent : secant
opposite / adjacent   : tangent       adjacent / opposite : cotangent
```

Which of these ratios is not useful?

The fact that all of these can be determined from the others is irrelevant. By the same logic as your question, why use more than just one of the six names?

While they all describe the same thing, a triangle, they do it from useful, even if different, perspectives.

Answer (score 3):

*Because $-1$ has no root in the reals.*

Both sine and cosine can be defined as solutions to the differential equation
$$
  f''(x) = -1 \cdot f(x).
$$
Which one you get depends only on the boundary condition.

Now, if the second derivative is so useful, then surely the first derivative should matter too! It's tempting to write
$$
  f'(x) = \sqrt{-1} \cdot f(x).
$$
and indeed it kind of works: it gives the complex function $\backslash t \mapsto e^{it}$. But for the applications the trigonometric functions were invented for – geometry, physics... – complex numbers can't really be used, as in, you can't measure a complex quantity.

To stay in the reals, we just leave the definition a second-order differential equation, but also give the first derivative a name of its own.

Comment: Mh, isn't that a counter-argument ? The first order equation has a single solution $Ze^{it}$, which corresponds to a sinusoid with indeterminate phase and amplitude, like $A\cdot\sin(t;\phi)$ or $A\cdot \sin_\phi(t)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: but the first-order equation can't even be phrased without complex numbers. And though complex numbers are of course a greatly useful concept, there are good reasons to also know how to live without them.

Answer (score 3):

Before calculators and computers we had tables of values trig functions. Having all the trig functions: $\sin, \cos, \sec, \csc, \tan, \cot$ made doing geometric calculations easier. You didn't have to first convert a cos into a sin before looking it up in the tables. It saved a step.

The $\sec$ and $\csc$ came into mathematical fashion when calculations for sailing ships across oceans were easier using them.

You can read more about the history of trig functions over thousands of years at http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Trigonometric_functions.html

Comment: I'd like to add a reference to the diagram on wikipedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Circle-trig6.svg -- A dozen different named and highly redundant trig functions.  Many have fallen out of use, but they all were named at one point.

Comment: Nice diagram! I can imagine the midshipmen on 18th century sailing ship learning all these trig functions to do their spherical geometry calculations to figure out where the ship was today. :-)

Answer (score 2):

They must both have names in order to preserve the symmetry when writing down relationships: in complex arithmetics ($e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$) or in calculus ($\sin' x=\cos x$), we see that they are two parts of the same coin, so if you only keep the name of one, expressions become lopsided and just plain ugly. You could just define one (and for the purpose of computing it numerically, you can certainly use just one to compute both), but in math, you want elegance.

Speaking of, a more pertinent question would be, why do $\csc$ and $sec$ exist. They have no real use except for creating confusion: they are fractions, don't naturally arise from linear relationships (sin/cos are components of complex numbers, describe rotation, solutions to common differential equations) and, most importantly, they make otherwise simple expressions look unrecognizable and unreadable.

Comment: Secants were of major interest to the maritime schools and unsolved problems for many years with regards to secants made it a major topic of curiosity probably.

Comment: @user507974 of course, there are problems when you need to divide by a cosine. But mathematically, there is no elegance or structure that would make defining sec=1/cos better instead of worse. There are just twice as many relationships between functions to remember. It's sort of like invention of grads as angular units for the sake of "convenience".

Answer (score 2):

This is an elaboration on Vectornaut's answer and hopefully more elementary than most others; actually two viewpoints.  The explanations are kept elementary in order to emphasize the origin of calculations sin() and cos() and subsequent relations like the one in the question are based long after the original terms and are reflections of underlying symetries that people needed and wanted.

Consider any curve on a plane (or in space if you like the reasoning is the same.  To embed it in a mathematical structure we can envision writing the curve paramatricized by s thusly (x(s),y(s).  Now we use this technique to describe a circle with a parameterization of distance from the center and angle from x.  We get:
$$\left(r\cdot \cos(\theta\right),r\cdot \sin\left(\theta\right))$$
In the abstract the terms are simply names for calculating the (x,y) coordinates for a particular curve.  The identity mentioned is a reflection of the symmetry of that particular curve.  If I had defined a hyperbola I would still have equations for (x,y) but they wouldn't have that particular symmetry; and the question wouldn't have been asked since the OP would see that two different functions would be expected with different relationships.  All of the other properties of sin(),cos() are inherited from the underlying symmetry.
The alternate explanation comes from dropping the "r" dependence.  Although this seems it would be more abstract but historically it was first :)
In ancient time people still had property boundaries and wanted to measure and design things remotely; say by drawing for communication.  In order to layout property or build a temple some way of scaling had to be invented.  Our ancestors found out the ratios of certain triangles were constant and therefore models or drawings could be scaled down; this can also be considered a symmetry.  On areas of the earth that are relatively flat we have the ratios
$$ \left(\cos(\theta\right),\sin\left(\theta\right))$$
(They were as smart as we think we are)
Since they didn't know any of the properties to start with they simply called the ratios different names.  We discovered a multitude of properties later; over 1000's of years.

I hope the readers will forgive the emphasis on symmetries but I am studying Lie Groups/Algebras and they seem to be advanced versions and descriptions of symmetries like the above.

Comment: Up-voted for the key point: "Since they didn't know any of the properties to start with they simply called the ratios different names. We discovered a multitude of properties later; over 1000's of years."

Comment: @RayatERISCorp Thanks, I really didn't expect any points for this but I thought the question showed a lack of mathematical "maturity".  In this case I thought an elementary explanation in a historical context was appropriate.  Hopefully this provides motivation and knowledge to encourage younger people; rather than making someone feel dumb about not having a deep background.

Answer (score 1):

Having both $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ allows you to uniquely identify a point on the unit circle. $sin(x)$ is insufficient since you would also have to know $x$ to deduce  $sin(\frac{\pi}{2} + x)$, which in turn renders $sin(x)$ useless since $x$ already uniquely identifies said point.

Answer (score 0):

Just as every *individual has a name , different from others* ; so should every *function* have a name *different from others* .
 This enables us to remember different functions *in short*, without having to write the *detailed mathematical expressions , representting these functions*.

Comment: If _every_ function had a name, then these names would need to be so long to be unique that it would be easier to “inline” the defining expression. (Or, really, it would just be impossible, because there are clearly uncountable-infinitely many functions.) Alternatively, if the names weren't unique, it would be extremely confusing (actually, that's a problem in particular physics has already).

Comment: @leftaroundabot It is_particle_ physics...

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to saying that why do spoon and fork exist even thought both of them do somewhat similar jobs....

Again yes there is a way to write cosine in terms of sine but if we write everything in sine the question which you will get will not look friendly. The more simple something is more is the motivation for you to do it.

**Mathematics is all about making complicated things simpler not simpler things complicated**

Answer (score 0):

In a right triangle, the three basic trig functions sine, secant, and tangent are related to their co-functions cosine, cosecant, and cotangent by having the same relation to the sides of the triangle, but from the point of view of the complementary angle.  For example, in a triangle with angles 30, 60, and 90, the sine of 30 is the cosine of 60. In this sense, the cosine and sine are complements; really one thing and its complement, not two separate things.

Answer (score 0):

I think that cos is just the shortcut for **co**sine, so it is somehow derived. You have vectors and **co**vectors and all kinds of other duaities in math.

Unlike the others here, I don't really think we need two different names -- and indeed, we don't have them.