# Seeking elegant proof of $\sum_{cyc}\cot(x-y)\cot(y-z)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, alternative-proof, elliptic-integrals

## Problem

The following identity is obvious:
$$
\frac{1}{(x-y)(y-z)} + \frac{1}{(y-z)(z-x)} + \frac{1}{(z-x)(x-y)} = 0
$$

This post is for a trigonometric version in terms of cotangent:
$$
\cot (x- y) \cot( y- z) + \cot( y-z) \cot( z - x) + \cot ( z- x) \cot ( x-y) = 1
$$

The following Mathematica code gives me 1

```
Simplify[Cot[x - y] Cot[y - z] + Cot[z - x] Cot[y - z] +  Cot[x - y] Cot[z - x]]
```

So I think the identity is right.

I could have proved it using a brute force expansion in terms of trigonometric functions of $x, y,z$ individually.
But I feel there definitely is a more elegant proof. I'm looking for such a proof.

**Follow-up question**: is there a similar identity involving the elliptic function sn, cn, dn? I don't know the answer, but it is possible based on the context of the real world problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Mathematica's trigonometric algebra shows that it is correct. "A brute force expansion" in the post means that I can do TrigExpand for both ```Cos[x - y] Cos[y - z] Sin[z - x] + Cos[x - y] Sin[y - z] Cos[z - x] + Sin[x - y] Cos[y - z] Cos[z - x]``` and ```Sin[x - y] Sin[y - z] Sin[z - x]``` in terms of products like ```Cos[x] Cos[y]^2 Sin[x]``` etc. Again I checked in Mathematica, they are identical. What would be my proof. But I admit that I didn't check manually on paper.

Comment: This is equivalent to $$\tan(x-y)+\tan(y-z)+\tan(z-x)=\tan(x-y)\cdot\tan(y-z)\cdot\tan(z-x).$$

Comment: it follows from something like $\tan(a+b) = \dfrac{\tan a + \tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b}$ and letting $c = -a-b$ and make an appropriate $x,y,z$ substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Given any three numbers $\;x,y,z\;$ define
$$ X := e^{ix},\; Y := e^{iy},\; := e^{iz}\quad
\text{ and }\quad a := X^2,\; b := Y^2,\; c := Z^2. $$
Then, by definition of cotangent
$\; \cot(x-y) = i(a+b)/(a-b).\;$ Thus
$$ \cot(x-y)\cot(y-z) = -\frac{(a+b)(b+c)}{(a-b)(b-c)}. $$
Cycle, add, and use common denominator to get
$$  1 - \sum_{cyc}\cot(x-y)\cot(y-z)  = \frac{S}{ (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)} $$
where $$ S := (a\!-\!b)(b\!-\!c)(c\!-\!a) \!+\!
  (a\!+\!b)(b\!+\!c)(c\!-\!a)\!+\!
   (a\!-\!b)(b\!+\!c)(c\!+\!a)\!+\!
  (a\!+\!b)(b\!-\!c)(c\!+\!a) .$$
Now $\;S\;$ expands to identically zero. There are several ways
to verify this. For example, if
$$ T(b) := (a-b)(b-c)+(a+b)(b+c) = (b+b)(c+a),$$
(which is equivalent to id$_{3,3,1,2e}$) then $S = T(b)(c-a) + T(-b)(c+a), $ but $ T(b)=-T(-b). $
Thus, $\;0 = S\;$ is the identity named as id$_{3,4,1,3b}$
in my collection of hundreds of [Special Algebraic Identities](https://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/%7Esomos/ident04.html). This answers
your main question.

You also asked

> **Follow-up question**: is there a similar identity involving the elliptic function sn, cn, dn? I don't know the answer, but it is possible based on the context of the real world problem.

Depends on what precisely you mean by "similar identity". I suggest that you
look at my identities for those tagged `[JE]` just as id$_{3,4,1,3b}$. That
is, this identity is already satisfied by Jacobi sn, sc, sd. More precisely,
suppose the function $\;f\;$ is any one of $\;\sin,\;\tan,\;$sn, sc, sd.
Then
$$ 0 = f(a-b)f(b-c)f(c-a) + f(a+b)f(b+c)f(c-a) + \\
   f(a-b)f(b+c)f(c+a) +  f(a+b)f(b-c)f(c+a).  $$

There are several other identities labeled `[JE]`
that all have the same solutions as this identity.

This is related to
[MSE question 4088531](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4088531/)
about functional equations for both sine and tangent.

Comment: It is indeed a proof. One converts a trigonometric identity into algebraic identities of the exponential. I up voted the answer. But the proof is done by an explicit computation. I will wait to see other proofs. The "elegant proof" I am looking, I hope, can provide guidance to the case of the elliptic functions.

Comment: @anecdote What "guidance"? My equation is already the elliptic function case.