# How do we know that sine and cosine exist?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

There is a question with the same title on the math StackExchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1416053/397764). However, I am asking a different question: under the definition of them as the right triangle ratios $$\sin(\theta)=\frac{\textrm{opposite}}{\textrm{hypotenuse}}$$ and $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{\textrm{adjacent}}{\textrm{hypotenuse}},$$
how do we (rigorously) know that they stay constant for a given $\theta$ for any right triangle?

Comment: corresponding sides of similar triangles are proportional

Comment: Yeah... how do we know this ?

Comment: @A.Lavie: Thales theorem

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equiangular_Triangles_are_Similar